# How to understand sample_weight in sklearn.metrics?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

Do we need to set sample_weight when we evaluate our model? Now I have trained a model about classification, but the dataset is unbalanced. When I set the sample_weight with compute_sample_weight('balanced'), the scores are very nice. Precision:0.88, Recall:0.86 for '1' class.
But the scores will be bad if I don't set the sample_weight. Precision:0.85, Recall:0.21.
Will the sample_weight destroy the original data distribution?

Answer (score 0):

The sample-weight parameter is only used during training.

Suppose you have a dataset with 16 points belonging to class "0" and 4 points belonging to class "1".

Without this parameter, during optimization, they have a weight of 1 for loss calculation: they contribute equally to the loss that the model is minimizing. That means that 80% of the loss is due to points of class "0" and 20% is due to points of class "1".

By setting it to "balanced", scikit-learn will automatically calculate weights to assign to class "0" and class "1" such that 50% of the loss comes from class "0" and 50% from class "1".

This paramete affects the "optimal threshold" you need to use to separate class "0" predictions from class "1", and also influences the performance of your model.

Comment: So we just need to set sample_weight or use imbalanced-learn methods to train our model? Then why sklearn set this parameter in metrics? I don't think it is a good idea to set it when we want to check our scores. We will be misdirected by these "false" scores.

Comment: The use of this parameter during training will give you a different model (as most hyper parameters do). During evaluation, it's true that certain function accept a "sample weight" or "class weight" parameter (for example f1-score) that will change the way they calculate the performance. It's up to you to choose the metric which suits the best your objective (what do you plan to do with the model) (accuracy vs F1-score vs auc ...)
These are not "false" scores, they are different with different meanings

Comment: The sampling weight is NOT only used during training, but also in validation/testing as well. Especially when we compare multiple models on different test set with metrics such as pr AUC, it's often desirable to balance the tests set.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my understanding: The sample_weight have nothing to do with balanced or unbalanced on itself, it is just a way to reflect the distribution of the sample data. So basically the following two way of expression is equivalent, and expression 1 is definitely more efficient in terms of space complexity. This 'sample_weight' is just the same as any other statistical package in any language and have nothing about the random sampling

expression 1

```
X = [[1,1],[2,2]]
y = [0,1]
sample_weight = [1000,2000]  # total 3000
```

versus

expression 2

```
X = [[1,1],[2,2],[2,2],...,[1,1],[2,2],[2,2]] # total 300 rows
y = [0,1,1,...,0,1,1]
sample_weight = [1,1,1,...,1,1,1]  # or just set as None
```